# PM2 - CPU 100% usage

Tags: pm2

I have an express server running with pm2(v2.4.2) and node(v7.7.4). Here is the `pm2 list` screenshot:

[image]

Here is `htop` screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the CPU usage is 100%. And the running PIDs are not match with pm2 list. My server would get no response after a few hours or days. I can't find any log from `pm2.log` file. Sometimes `pm2 restart` fix this. But sometimes I can't execute any `pm2` commands. I need to kill pm2 process by `ps -Af | grep pm2 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`
 and then restart.
So where are these two high cpu usage processes come from? That's why my server no response?

Comment: Your server not responding is because the CPU is at 100%. 1. When you run PM2 run pm2 list all .. see if that is what is eating up the cpu. However, from the log *it seems* that these are 2 other unrelated processes (not from PM2). See what else is running on your server, besides node.

Comment: @twg The first screenshot is the result for `pm2 list all`. There is no other thing running on this server. I didn't see 2 other unrelated processes you said. `node /root/git/feserver/bin/www` is my project entrance. The most confused thing is the running PIDs not match `pm2 list` result.

Comment: Based on your OS you should be able to get the name of the process running on those mysterious PID numbers. take a look here [StackOverflow](https://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name)

Comment: @Hom have you fixed the problem or is it still happening?. Are you using `chokidar` or watching file system changes? I had a similar problem a month ago.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande still happening. I don't use `chokidar` nor watching file changes. I wrote a cpu usage guard process to fix this.  Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/yanzhihong23/c9618d672eee0f467af872ea23a9f39c)

Comment: Did anybody try the solution on https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/141#issuecomment-49285837 ??

Answer (score 8):

If it can help someone, I had the same problem and I have fixed this by fallowing this update procedure [PM2 - Update](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/update-pm2/) and updated the startup setup script (copy/paste command). This problem seam to appear after upgrading Node, it may also help to `npm update` your servers running under PM2 after a Node version upgrade.